# iOS 9 search feature with deep linking

Tags: ios, swift, search, deep-linking, ios9

I want to implement a search feature with deep linking ability. Below is the code snippet I wrote, but deep linking is not working. Search always launches the app, but does not take to deep view controllers.
 Please let me know what is wrong with the below code. Thanks

```
let activity: NSUserActivity = NSUserActivity(activityType: "com.myproject.SearchTest1")
        activity.title = "My Search app"
        activity.userInfo = ["Search" : ["Icecream" , "Nuts", "Biscuits"]]
        if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
            activity.eligibleForSearch = true
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }

        if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
            activity.keywords = NSSet(array: ["Icecream" , "Nuts", "Biscuits"]) as! Set<String>
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
        activity.delegate = self
        activity.needsSave = true
        self.userActivity = activity
        activity.becomeCurrent()



override func updateUserActivityState(activity: NSUserActivity) {
        activity.title = self.userActivity?.title
        activity.addUserInfoEntriesFromDictionary(["Search" : ["Icecream" , "Nuts", "Biscuits"]])
        super.updateUserActivityState(activity)
    }
```

My App delegate code is below:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, continueUserActivity userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: ([AnyObject]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
        if let window = self.window {
            window.rootViewController?.restoreUserActivityState(userActivity)
        }
        return true
    }
```

Comment: What is not working? What is it doing? What do you expect it to do?

Comment: Do you want core spotlight or user activities?

Answer (score 0):

Clicking on the search result from spotlight will go to continueUserActivity method.

You pass the userActivity to the rootViewController of the app’s window and return true. This tells the OS you handled the Handoff action successfully. From this point on, you are on your own to forward calls and restore the activity.
The method you call on the rootViewController is restoreUserActivityState (activity:).

Your task now is to walk down the view controller hierarchy and pass the activity from the parent to child view controllers until reach the point where the activity is consumed

```
override func restoreUserActivityState(activity: NSUserActivity) {
 let nextViewController = childViewControllers.first as!UIViewController
 nextViewController.restoreUserActivityState(activity)
 super.restoreUserActivityState(activity)
}
```

If you followed this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/84174/ios-8-handoff-tutorial), you have to finish it completely.